# Is "types" the equivalent of "main" for TypeScript projects?

Tags: typescript, node-modules, package.json

From the [module resolution docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html):

> Similarly, a non-relative import will follow the Node.js resolution
>   logic, first looking up a file, then looking up an applicable folder.
>   So `import { b } from "moduleB"` in source file `/root/src/moduleA.ts`
>   would result in the following lookups:
>
> 1. `/root/src/node_modules/moduleB.ts`
> 2. `/root/src/node_modules/moduleB.tsx`
> 3. `/root/src/node_modules/moduleB.d.ts`
> 4. `/root/src/node_modules/moduleB/package.json` (if it specifies a `"types"` property)
> 5. `/root/src/node_modules/@types/moduleB.d.ts`
> 6. `/root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.ts`
> 7. `/root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.tsx`
> 8. `/root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.d.ts`

So TypeScript doesn't seem to take the "main" property into account  (as Node.js [does](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules)), but it does look for "types". Are they equivalent, or does the latter only import *.d.ts files?

Comment: Step 4 looks wrong. where are you getting that from?

Comment: As mentioned in the post, from [the official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

Comment: I think that's just how TS resolves typings. It can still use the node module resolution strategy to take `main` into account, which is also mentioned in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about properties of a `package.json` file. If this is the case, as you guessed, `types` is an entry used by *TypeScript* to load the typing (and only the typing) of the module. The `main` entry is still required to load the *JavaScript* side of the module.

Comment: Great. So if `types` pointed to an actual module with logic and variables inside, I can't import it this way, can I?

Comment: You need to have a `main` (or an `exports` in new versions of _NodeJS_), or node will not be able to import it. This is a runtime condition. When developing with _TypeScript_, your tool will only care of the `types` entry in order to type check your use of the import. Your type definition files may be in the same directory as the main module files, so in this case, `types` may (also) point to a full module logic.